# Redirecting Process StandardInput, StandardOutput and StandardError in c#

Tags: c#, process, compilation, inputstream, io-redirection

I want to compile a java program using batch file. Code works if the program does not need any input but creates a deadlock condition when it needs input
Here is the code:

```
    public void compilefile(ref System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox rtb,ref TabItem tabitem)
    {
        var range = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);

        FileInfo filetocompile = new FileInfo(Path.GetTempPath() + tabitem.Header.ToString());
        using (FileStream fs = filetocompile.Open(FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            range.Save(fs, System.Windows.DataFormats.Text);
            fs.Close();
        }

     try{

            pf = new ProcessStartInfo(@"E:\com.bat");
            pf.FileName = @"E:\com.bat";
            pf.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_13\\bin\\\"", "javac", tabitem.Header.ToString(), "java", tabitem.Header.ToString().Substring(0, tabitem.Header.ToString().LastIndexOf('.')));
            pf.CreateNoWindow = true;
            pf.ErrorDialog = false;
            pf.UseShellExecute = false;
            pf.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            pf.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            pf.RedirectStandardError = true;
            pf.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetTempPath();
            p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = pf;
            p.Start();
            input = p.StandardInput;
            string inputstring = "";
            input.AutoFlush = true;

            do
            {
                if (p.StandardError.ReadToEnd() != "")
                {
                    consoleTextBlock.IsDocumentEnabled = false;
                    consoleTextBlock.AppendText(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
                    consoleTextBlock.AppendText(p.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
                 }
                else
                {
                    consoleTextBlock.AppendText(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
                    consoleTextBlock.AppendText(p.StandardError.ReadToEnd());

                }

                consoleTextInput.Focus();
                consoleTextBlock.ScrollToEnd();
                consoleTextBlock.IsReadOnly = true;
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(p.ExitCode.ToString());
            } while (p.HasExited != true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

        }
    }
```

What should i use to redirect input? Please help as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Input first, then read both output streams after the event, like this:

```
    //..
    string[] inputLines = {"your", "input", "goes", "here"}
    //..
    //..
    p.Start();

    using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
    {
        if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
            foreach(string line in inputLines) sw.WriteLine(line);
    }
    string output = "+"; 
    string outputErr = "-";
    output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    outputErr = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: but this works only for limited number of inputs.. what if , a process needs more or less inputs depending upon the compiler's response

Comment: Well, you asked about a batch file first, right? I guess you could restructure the code and insert an output check after each line input and use a List<String> to read the input from instead of an array, to which you could add lines if needed; but I haven't been there myself. Come to think of it, I'll try that for my own pet project (emulating a DOS box) later today..

Comment: From MS documentation:
 `ReadToEnd assumes that the stream knows when it has reached an end. For interactive protocols in which the server sends data only when you ask for it and does not close the connection, ReadToEnd might block indefinitely because it does not reach an end, and should be avoided.` So one change should probably be reading the streams differently eg with  `Read(Char[], Int32, Int32)`, but that is only top of my head atm..

Comment: ReadLine would probably be more adequate. ((Darn the time limit for editing comments!Seems buggy,too!!))